# Wazuh4.3 Api sent a post request to modify the role error

Tags: wazuh

I am using the Wazuh4.3 API to modify the user role using a post request, but return the Missing query parameter 'role to me_ Ids, could you please tell me how to solve it

I have checked the official latest documentation, but I have not found a solution. There is very little information on the latest version on the search engine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to switch the role a user belongs to in this way:

```
# Unassign previous role (optional)
curl -k -X DELETE "https://localhost:55000/security/users/<USER_ID>/roles?role_ids=<ROLE_ID>" -H  "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"

# Assign new role
curl -k -X POST "https://localhost:55000/security/users/<USER_ID>/roles?role_ids=<NEW_ROLE_ID>" -H  "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
```

For example:

```
# Unassign previous role (optional)
curl -k -X DELETE "https://localhost:55000/security/users/100/roles?role_ids=100" -H  "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"

# Assign new role
curl -k -X POST "https://localhost:55000/security/users/100/roles?role_ids=101" -H  "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
```

You can list the current users (id, name and roles) and roles like this:

```
# List users
curl -k -X GET "https://localhost:55000/security/users?pretty=True" -H  "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
# List roles
curl -k -X GET "https://localhost:55000/security/roles?pretty=True" -H  "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
```

Here is the full API reference for the latest version, in case you find it useful:

- [API reference - Wazuh](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/api/reference.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's too unreliable to refer to the official documents. Perhaps the posture I visited is incorrect ->https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/api/reference.html#api-reference